# Why is my Blazor Server page empty after publishing to IIS?

Tags: c#, .net-core, iis, blazor, windows-task-scheduler

I'm developing a Blazor Server app that exposes Windows Task Scheduler tasks for remote control with limited controls (I know I can remote to the server's Task Scheduler but this is a request to make it available to some other users inside my organization via local website). The library to access Windows Task Scheduler is `Microsoft.Win32.TaskScheduler` from NuGet. The app is pretty simple with only 1 component, user is authenticated with Windows Authentication, the app is hosted on an application server's IIS. I'm also new to Blazor and I'm learning by doing it.

Razor page

```
@page "/"

<h3>Task Manager</h3>

<div>
    @if (TaskList == null)
    {
        <div class="spinner"></div>
    }
    else
    {
        @foreach (var task in TaskList)
        {
            <p>
                @task.Name -
                @task.State -
                @task.Enabled
            </p>
            <p>
                @task.LastRunTime -
                @task.NextRunTime -
                @task.LastTaskResult
            </p>
            <p>
                <input id="btnPause" type="button" disabled="@(task.Enabled ? false : true)" value="Pause" @onclick="() => DisableTask(task)" />
                <input id="btnResume" type="button" disabled="@(task.Enabled ? true : false)" value="Resume" @onclick="() => EnableTask(task)" />
                <input id="btnRun" type="button" disabled="@(task.Enabled ? false : true)" value="Run now" @onclick="() => RunTask(task)" />
                <input id="btnStop" type="button" disabled="@(task.Enabled ? false : true)" value="Stop" @onclick="() => EndTask(task)" />
            </p>
            <br />
        }
    }
</div>
```

Code behind

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.Win32.TaskScheduler;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;

namespace TaskSchedulerManager.Pages
{
    public partial class TaskManager: ComponentBase
    {
        public IEnumerable<Task> TaskList { get; set; }

        protected override System.Threading.Tasks.Task OnInitializedAsync()
        {
            LoadScheduleTask();
            return base.OnInitializedAsync();
        }

        private void LoadScheduleTask()
        {
            using (TaskService ts = new TaskService())
            {
                TaskFolder root = ts.RootFolder;
                TaskFolder sub = root.SubFolders["Task Scheduler Folder Name"];
                List<Task> tsList = new List<Task>();
                foreach (Task task in sub.Tasks)
                {
                    tsList.Add(task);
                }
                TaskList = new List<Task>(tsList);
            }
        }

        private void DisableTask(Task task)
        {
            task.Enabled = false;
            InvokeAsync(() =>
            {
                StateHasChanged();
            });
        }

        private void EnableTask(Task task)
        {
            task.Enabled = true;
            InvokeAsync(() =>
            {
                StateHasChanged();
            });
        }

        private void RunTask(Task task)
        {
            task.Run();
            InvokeAsync(() =>
            {
                StateHasChanged();
            });
        }

        private void EndTask(Task task)
        {
            task.Stop();
            InvokeAsync(() =>
            {
                StateHasChanged();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

When I run it locally, all the tasks are displayed on the page as intended. When I publish the app to IIS, the page only shows the header *Task Manager*, below that it's empty, on the same machine or from local machine. What did I miss?

Comment: Most probably the IIS user doesn't have permissions to access the tasks

Comment: How do I add permissions to read tasks? And to which user specifically?

Comment: I don't know. Some googling says you should give access to the scheduled tasks folder C:\Windows\System32\Tasks . The user account that needs this access is probably IUSR. Not sure though

Comment: I found a partial solution. In the using statement, if I enter a remote server and credentials, it will work for that server, per the instructions:

`
using (TaskService ts = new TaskService(@"\\RemoteServer", "username", "domain", "password"))
`
If I don't pass server credentials (aka local service), it will not work

Comment: not sure but if you use .net-core would a dotnet run run the app inside an express version ? so you wouldn't need a IIS ?

Comment: I need to host it as a website so other users can use.

Answer (score 0):

Webpage was just an empty page because the order of rendering was incorrect.

```cs
protected override System.Threading.Tasks.Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    LoadScheduleTask();
    return base.OnInitializedAsync();
}
```

change to

```cs
return base.OnInitializedAsync();
LoadScheduleTask();
// terminal task...
```

or something another, always remember order of HTML rendering. Blazor's nature is render HTML by WebAssembly code.